# How to change Window.Forms Application Icon

Tags: winforms, f#, icons

I am trying to change the Window Icon using the System.Forms library.

```
open System
open System.Drawing
open System.Windows.Forms

let window = new Form()
window.Text <- "Hallo!"

let icon = new System.Drawing.Icon("icon.png")
window.Icon <- icon

Application.Run window
```

My code doesn't return any errors and compiles like a charm. But! i get an unhandled exception stating that the argument picture must be a picture that can be used as an icon.

So what are the requirements for the picture? the present one i got is a png and is 512x512 in dimensions.

The official discription of the Icon property is found here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.icon(v=vs.110).aspx

So i take it the problem is that the attempted match the requested size fails. But what is the requested size?

Comment: The first para:graph says: "Represents a Windows icon, which is a small **bitmap** image that is used to represent an object. Icons can be thought of as transparent bitmaps, although their size is determined by the system.

Comment: A PNG is a bitmap image too, but not suitable as an icon.  Only a file in the .ico file format can be used.  Size limitations apply as well, can't be bigger than 256x256 and you should include multiple sizes so they fit well on the title bar, the Explorer view and the desktop.  Beyond using a dedicated icon editor, consider using the one built into VS.  Project > Add New Item > Icon.  Using a freeware icon is never a bad idea, creating good looking icons is not that easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using png image as an icon of windows forms. Use .ico file as an icon. Convert icon from [here](http://convertico.com/), this site will convert png to ico with all sizes available.